# Operation hours redesign

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on a requirement that has the 'Hours of operation' data as below:

[image]

The data here should have to display in a different manner. Meaning - I am trying to combine the Hours of operation on days and open/close hours. My expected result is:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this set of results? I have created a temp table with this data in the below `rextester` link.

https://rextester.com/EMF48033

Code:

```
select programid, 
       concat(max(case when [order] = 1 then day end),' ','-',' ', max(case when [order] = max_order then day end)) as day,
       times
from (select programid, day, [order], max([order]) over (partition by programid) as max_order,
             STUFF((SELECT ',' + concat([open], ' ','-',' ', [close]) FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') as times
      from #temp
      group by programid, day, [order],[open], [close]
     ) pd
group by programid, times
order by times desc
```

Comment: Please ensure your question is self contained with all the data and queries in plain text within the question. Links to external SQL test sites are OK, but in addition to having the query in the question. Images are highly discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

For your sample data, this works:

```
select programid, 
       concat_ws('-', max(case when [order] = 1 then day end), max(case when [order] = max_order then day end)) as day,
       times
from (select programid, day, [order], max([order]) over (partition by programid) as max_order,
             string_agg(concat([open], '-', [close]), '\n') within group (order by convert(time, [open])) as times
      from temp
      group by programid, day, [order]
     ) pd
group by programid, times;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6fb5e2450a764a9a3981874368b2581) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: this doesn't work for me in SQL 2012 version. Can you modify concat_ws and string_agg?

Comment: I have edited your code with stuff instead of string_agg and it works fine. But I am seeing redundant records. meaning - I am unable to group the hours based on ProgramId. Can you pls check? Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you'd be happy with an 'and' instead of a new line, but this works in SQL 2012.  The use of `cross apply` looks a little cumbersome but that's because I'd rather define it once to run the `left` around rather than repeat it:

```
 ;

with cte as (
    select
    programid,
    t1.[day],
    [order],
    left(ot.OpeningTimes,len(ot.OpeningTimes)-4) as OpeningTimes,
    min(t1.[order]) over (partition by t1.programid order by t1.[order] asc) as StartOrder,
    max(t1.[order]) over (partition by t1.programid order by t1.[order] desc) as EndOrder
    from #temp as t1
    cross apply (
        select (
            select concat([open],' - ',[close], ' and ')
            from #temp as t2
            where t1.programid = t2.programid
                and t1.[day] = t2.[day]
            for xml path('')
        ) as OpeningTimes
        from #temp as t3
        where t1.programid = t3.programid
            and t1.[day] = t3.[day]
    ) as ot 
    group by programid, [day], [order], OpeningTimes
    )

select
cte.programid,
concat(sd.[day],' - ',ed.[day]) as OpeningDays,
cte.OpeningTimes
from cte
inner join cte as sd on sd.programid = cte.programid
        and sd.[order] = sd.StartOrder
inner join cte as ed on ed.programid = cte.programid
        and ed.[order] = ed.EndOrder
group by cte.programid, sd.[day], ed.[day], cte.OpeningTimes
```